# Best approach for migrating the "wrong" foreign key to the "correct" foreign key?

Tags: mysql, laravel-6

For context, I have a Laravel 6 project which made a rather odd choice, to put it mildly, on how to manage relationships when I inherited it.

I have a user object which has it's usual autoincrement id, as well as a "system_id" which is provided by an external system.

For most of the project, relationships involving a user object make use of their "id" field as the foreign key in the belongsTo() part of the relationship which is all well and good.

However, one many-to-many relationship, specifically the one used for the relationship between a user model and a group model, uses the user model's "system_id" field as the foreign key instead of the usual "id" field used everywhere else which is beginning to cause all kinds of development headaches, and is already in production.

So as part of a cleanup project of the system, I intend on migrating the pivot table to use the user model's "id" field. The challenge now is the following:

1. In a database-agnostic way, how to copy the matching id to the "user_id" foreign key field in the pivot table given a known "system_id".
2. How will it look in a migration? Is a migration even a good option or should it be done directly in the database instead?
3. Anything else I should account for?
4. Is this even a good idea in the first place or should we just live with it?

Obviously, a backup will be made and the whole thing will be tested in a test environment first before it's attempted in production.